# Adding JavaCard 3.0.4 to Netbeans 8.2 as new JC Platform

Tags: netbeans, javacard

I am trying to add a newly installed JCDK 3.0.4 to Netbeans 8.2 while copying over the platform.properties from the default JC 3.0.2 found in the Netbeans 8.2 bundle.

I am getting an indication that the newly added JC 3.0.4 platform is an invalid platform.

I would need access to JC 3.0.4 API as the JC 3.0.2 in the standard Netbeans 8.2 installation does not have the necessary APIs I am looking for.

The platform.properties as follows:

```
# Various properties used by Tools.
javacard.name=Java Card Platform
javacard.vendor=Sun Microsystems
javacard.version=3.0.4
javacard.java.majorVersion=1
javacard.java.minorVersion=6
javacard.edition=connected
javacard.distribution.scope=domestic
javacard.home=C:\JCDK304
javacard.emulator=classic_simulator/bin/cjcre.exe
javacard.bootclasspath=lib/api_connected.jar
javacard.classic.bootclasspath=lib/api_classic.jar
javacard.classpath=
javacard.javadocpath=docs/api/
javacard.sourcepath=src/api/
javacard.toolClassPath=lib/tools.jar:lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:lib/bcel-5.2.jar:lib/commons-cli-

1.0.jar:lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar:lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar
javacard.nbtasksClassPath=lib/nbtasks.jar:lib/nbutils.jar
javacard.platform.kind=RI
javacard.device.file.extension=jcard
#
javacard.runtime.name=Java Card Runtime Environment
javacard.specification.version=3.0.4
javacard.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
javacard.referenceimplementation.version=3.0.4
javacard.referenceimplementation.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
javacard.referenceimplementation.httpPort=yes
javacard.referenceimplementation.contactedPort=yes
javacard.referenceimplementation.contactlessPort=yes
#Supported app models
javacard.platform.supported.project.kinds=web,extended-applet,classic-applet,extension-lib,classic-lib
#tools/task class names
javacard.apdutoolClass=com.sun.javacard.apdutool.Main
javacard.tasks.packTaskClass=com.sun.javacard.nbtasks.PackTask
javacard.tasks.signTaskClass=com.sun.javacard.nbtasks.SignTask
javacard.tasks.proxyTaskClass=com.sun.javacard.nbtasks.ProxyTask
javacard.tasks.loadTaskClass=com.sun.javacard.nbtasks.LoadTask
javacard.tasks.createTaskClass=com.sun.javacard.nbtasks.CreateTask
javacard.tasks.deleteTaskClass=com.sun.javacard.nbtasks.DeleteTask
javacard.tasks.unloadTaskClass=com.sun.javacard.nbtasks.UnloadTask
javacard.tasks.browseTaskClass=com.sun.javacard.nbtasks.OpenBrowserTask
```

All the JAR files listed in the properties files are existing.

How do I fix the above problem as I need to develop on Netbeans 8.2 on an issued workstation ?

Comment: I don't know the answer on this one, but it may be helpful if you include the exact error message rather than "I  am getting an indication...".